# How can i get tag content in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get content of two tags when i click on a special tag. How can I get "Lorem product" and "$23.00" when i click on tag a 
`<a class="btn" href="#">...</a>` thanks.

```
<div class="item">
    <!-- Item's image -->
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/1/" alt="">
    <!-- Item details -->
    <div class="item-dtls">
        <!-- product title -->
        <h4><a href="#" >Lorem product</a></h4>
        <!-- price -->
        <span class="price lblue"  >$23.00</span>
    </div>
    <!-- add to cart btn -->
    <div class="ecom bg-lblue">
        <a class="btn" href="#" ">Add to cart</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. If you want to post those values to server you need to have a form, input elements and a way to submit the form (submit button). Another way is to do the submit from jquery. Please edit your question and add more detail to understand what is the problem you are facing. Also, you forgot to include the code actually related to mvc (model and action)

Comment: well im programming in mvc and i wanna send those values to action result of this view when i click on that tag

Answer (score 0):

Example with simple postback with no jQuery:

**Sample Model**

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample Controller action**

```
public ActionResult IndexTest(TestModel model)
{
    var tmp = model;
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Your View revised**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.TestModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexTest", "Home"))
{
<div class="item">
    <!-- Item's image -->
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/1/" alt="">
    <!-- Item details -->
    <div class="item-dtls">
        <!-- product title -->
        <h4><a href="#">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)</a></h4>
        <!-- price -->
        <span class="price lblue">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price)</span>
    </div>
    <!-- add to cart btn -->
    <div class="ecom bg-lblue">
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

If you want to have *anchor* instead of *button*, you can call `.submit()` with jQuery on this anchor selector and POST to Controller in a same manner.

**jQuery .submit() doc:** https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Also, I would recommend reading some tutorials of ASP.NET MVC as these are core basics of how it works.

If you want to submit with anchor tag, swap button with this:

```
<a href ="#" class="btn" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Add to cart</a>
```

Will submit form in which it's nested.
I would recommend to extract it to `<script>` for cleaner HTML code.

Comment: I want get "Lorem product" and "$23.00" when i click on tag a  <a class="btn" href="#">...</a>

Comment: And you want to add the same value every time?

Comment: no, there is a view which consists of several items and  when i click on tag a <a class="btn" href="#">...</a> i want to get the name and price of the item

Comment: Updated the answer with submitting the form with anchor.

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` can be used to get the contents of any element. Try like following:

```
$('a.btn').click(function () {
     var container = $(this).closest('.item');
     var title = container.find('.item-dtls > h4 > a').html();
     var price = container.find('.price').html();
     alert('Title: ' + title + ', Price: ' + price);
});
```

Hope this will help you.